# Typescript type of key is `string` if key is template literal `a/${string}` or union

Tags: typescript

```
const a = 'a'
const obj = { [a]:1 } // {a:1}
```

this work as expected, however

```
const b = 'b/a' as `b/${string}`
const obj2 = { [b]:1 } // {[x:string]:1}, unexpected

const c=<T extends Record<string,unknown>>(arg:T):(keyof T & string)[]=>{
    return Object.keys(arg) 
}

const d = c(obj2) // string[], unexpected
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA5HFAoUlYgEYBWSMA3jANpwC6AXAIwwC+MGA9KzJ5wHoD8W4aDDzEUeVungQYAA3EASEtABOASzABzRjIE4Y+AgCZiZcnloNm7GAFcwAUwAeAB3vAo9gCZsOXPhl0hYEQAHgAVGCcPME9pACU3EGVPEJV1DQAaOwBrMBAAdzAAPiKACjhlDRowgEoaUuz7AE8QADMYCIAyGDTNGvIqRCKSDC4YZXsoG2UwGAB5QjcoADpGpohyypqWRgDsIU9iYFKDQ23rOydXdy8fMb4gA)

I need to infer the key type from generic, I did some experiment and found out that this is the issue

I was expecting **{[x:`b/${string}`]:1}**, but i get **{[x:string]:1}** instead

what is going on and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known deficiency in TypeScript, see [microsoft/TypeScript#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948).  When you use a computed property whose key is not of a single string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) in an object literal, the compiler widens the type of the key all the way to `string`, resulting in a type with a [string index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures).  This is usually not what people want to see, but it happens.   Now that [pattern template literal index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#symbol-and-template-string-pattern-index-signatures) are supported, this widening is even more noticeable (as I noted in [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948#issuecomment-940110068) on the referenced GitHub issue), as you've just experienced.  I don't know when or if this will be addressed.

In the meantime, the workaround I usually employ is to make a `kv()` function that takes a key and a value and produces a computed-key object with a more appropriate type:

```
const kv = <K extends PropertyKey, V>(k: K, v: V) =>
    ({ [k]: v }) as { [P in K]: { [Q in P]: V } }[K]
```

That return type is a "distributive [`Record<K, V>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) type" where any unions in the `K` type are distributed out to the final type, so that if the key is of type `A | B | C` and the value is of type `V` then the output is of type `Record<A, V> | Record<B, V> | Record<C, V>` (so it has *some* key) instead of the incorrect `Record<A | B | C, V>` (which has *all* keys).

You can test it here for template literals:

```
const obj3 = kv(b, 1);
/* const obj3: {
    [x: `b/${string}`]: number;
} */
```

And for unions as well:

```
const obj4 = kv(Math.random() < 0.5 ? a : b, 3);
/* const obj4: {
    [x: `b/${string}`]: number;
} | {
    a: number;
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)