# TypeScript indexed property not matching inferred generic type

Tags: typescript

This code fails to compile:

```
type Validator<T> = (value: string) => { value: T }

const createValidator = <TState extends any>(state: TState) =>
    <TName extends keyof TState>(x: TName, validator: Validator<TState[TName]>) => {
        return (value: { [P in TName]: string }): { [P in TName]: TState[TName] } => {
            const result = validator(value[x]);

            return { [x]: result.value };
        };
    }
```

`return { [x]: result.value };` gives me `Type '{ [x: string]: TState[TName]; }' is not assignable to type '{ [P in TName]: TState[TName]; }'.` even though TName is inferred from x.

Why is that? And what can I do about it - except from casting the returned value?

Comment: Could you add Validator type to complete the picture, please?

Comment: @yevt sure, yes, sorry. It's edited in now.

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a self-contained [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted as-is into a standalone IDE and does not have unrelated errors.  Right now `Validator` depends on other things we don't have access to.  You might want to clear that up either by defining those (and making sure that they doesn't point to further third-party types we don't have) or, even better, by replacing them with built-in types.

Comment: @jcalz yes, sorry about that. This was too hurried, I agree.

Comment: For sure @jcalz knows more about the key type narrowing in object literals and could correct my answer.

Comment: This is [microsoft/TypeScript#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948) and I usually keep around a `kv()` function as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73263242/2887218) to work around it.  I'd write up an answer but I see there's already an accepted answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is, that TypeScript doesn't infer index signatures in object literals with computed properties. The most minimal example:

```js
type KEY = 'foo' | 'bar';
let obj = { ['foo' as KEY]: 1 };

// obj is of type: { [x: string ]: number }
// and NOT the { foo: number, bar: number }
// and NOT the Record<'foo'|'bar', number>
```

So in your example you should cast, and to make it simpler, reuse types from variables to not repeat yourself:

```js
return { [x]: result.value } as Record<typeof x, typeof result.value>;
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there are any open issues regarding such feature?

Comment: FYI, this is [microsoft/TypeScript#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948) and I usually keep around a `kv()` function as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73263242/2887218) to work around it.