# computed properties circumvent typing in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typechecking, computed-properties

I found an issue with incorrect typings in our codebase that TypeScript provided no warnings for at all. I managed to narrow it down to a usage of computed properties. In the example function, we want to return a well-formed `UDFeatures` object:

```
type UDFeatures = {
  Person?: "FIRST"
  Case?: "NOM"
}

const getUDFeatures = (featName: keyof UDFeatures): UDFeatures => {
  // typing for the value here should be enforced as UDFeatures[keyof UDFeatures], but no checking is done
  let features: UDFeatures = {[featName]: "XYZ" }
  return features
}

// Prints {"Person": "XYZ"}, which is not a legal value for a UDFeatures object!
console.log(getUDFeatures("Person"))
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&noUnusedLocals=true&noUnusedParameters=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&noFallthroughCasesInSwitch=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature=true&suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors=true&ts=4.9.5&ssl=12&ssc=37&pln=1&pc=1&allowUnusedLabels=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgIgMQgQ2AVwE4QM5QLxQDeAUFFAAoQbYD2AdgPwBcUARAgJIBKAygCqtSUAMLJsEZmwByAeQCyggL7FiAY3rZgUAOYRg8JKkw58UABQAzFMCnIAthBYBrCCBoXYia8ewBKFgbeWLh4AHxEQgA2elBWRsEBXvEmBIQA2nE29hAAuiysABoAmgBarFDKZFjoGHSxQTjEysQA9C0UGACWdMC4hKyU1PSs+cVligA0UADuABadqrNQnbh0NFrIUNHayJFQAG67aNAWNBhQm4HJuDQARgBWEKrAAIRqGjTRAHSRNNpmun0SRqODMAyotDorF8vmIQA)

Given that `featName` is a key of `UDFeatures`, TypeScript should be able to tell that the value assignment must be a `UDFeatures[keyof UDFeatures]`, though I can understand that there is no general way to check that the key and value are a legal pairing, given that the computed property could be anything.

Is there a way to get TypeScript to do the stricter type checking that I expect here? If not, is there a config flag or lint I could use that would warn me (or prevent compilation) when type-checking is not possible in this scenario?

Comment: This is a longstanding bug in TypeScript, at [ms/TS#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948); when I need strict typing on computed properties I often introduce a helper `kv()` function to work around the issue, as shown [in this playground ink](https://tsplay.dev/WkDM9w). I'm thinking of closing this as a duplicate of [this q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73263242/2887218) since my answer would be essentially identical... unless there's something you think I'm missing about the question?

Comment: @jcalz your approach is an interesting one but it still fails even if you provide `FIRST` which should be a valid answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "provide `FIRST`"?  Do you mean if you return the equivalent of `{[featName]: "FIRST"}`?  But what if `featName` is `"Case"`?  Shouldn't the implementation complain because it doesn't know?  If `featName` were *known* to be `"Person"` inside the implementation then it should work, and it [does](https://tsplay.dev/W4j8vN). I'm not sure what you're expecting, could you walk me through it?

Comment: Ah, you are right. The problem here is, indeed, that the function does not know before hand what it will be provided with. Perhaps, for a case like this one where the values space is limited, overloading might also work (aside of yours, of course) although it does not fix the problem but instead it just circumvents it.

Comment: So do we agree that the issue is ms/TS#13948 and that working around it is the only current approach?  I'm just trying to make sure there isn't some subtlety I've missed when diagnosing the situation

Comment: Yes, this does appear to be the issue, thank you @jcalz. Do I understand correctly that the `kv` helper requires the value to be valid for any possible key `k`? The syntax is a bit hard to follow, but this would make sense. It will prevent usages that aren't guaranteed good.

Comment: Yeah, and that's probably how you'd want computed keys to behave also... no differently from how unions behave elsewhere.  If you want a value of type `"a" | number` and I hand you `const k = Math.random()<0.5 ? "a" : "b"` then you should complain, because `"b"` isn't a `number`. And if you want a `{a: Date} | {b: number}` and I hand you `{[k]: new Date()}` then you should complain for a similar reason.